# Shuffling Increasing Accuracy - sklearn - MultinomialNaiveBayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the accuracy of a Multinomial NaiveBayes algorithm in scikit-learn.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn import naive_bayes
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import random
from collections import Counter
dim0 = ['high', 'low', 'med', 'vhigh']
dim1 = ['high', 'low', 'med', 'vhigh']
dim2 = ['2', '3', '4', '5more']
dim3 = ['2', '4', 'more']
dim4 = [ 'big', 'med', 'small' ]
dim5 = ['high' , 'low', 'med' ]
target = ['acc', 'good', 'unacc', 'vgood' ]

dimensions = [ dim0, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5, target]

# function to read dataset
def readDataSet(fname):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    dataset = []
    for line in f:
        words = []
        tokenized = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(tokenized) != 7:
            continue
        for w in tokenized:
            words.append(w)
        dataset.append(np.array(words))
    return np.array(dataset)

# split the dataset into X - features and Y - labels / targets
# assumes last column of the data is the target
def XYfromDataset(dataset):
    X = []
    Y = []
    for d in dataset:
        X.append(np.array(d[:-1]))
        Y.append(d[-1])
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

def splitXY(X, Y, perc):
    splitpos = int(len(X) * perc)

    X_train = X[:splitpos]
    X_test = X[splitpos:]
    Y_train = Y[:splitpos]
    Y_test = Y[splitpos:]

    return (X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)


def mapDimension(dimen, mapping):
    res = []
    for d in dimen:
        res.append(float(mapping.index(d)))
    return np.array(res)


def runTrails( dataset, split = 0.66 ):    
    random.shuffle(dataset, random.random)

    (X,Y) = XYfromDataset(dataset)
    (X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test) = splitXY(X, Y, split)
    mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
    mnb.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    score = mnb.score(X_test, Y_test)
    mnb = None
    return score   





dataset = readDataSet('car.txt')
print "Class distributution:" , Counter(dataset[:,6])
for d in range(dataset.shape[1]):
    dataset[:, d] = mapDimension(dataset[: , d] , dimensions[d])
dataset = dataset.astype(float)

score = 0.0
num_trails = 10
for t in range(num_trails):
    acc = runTrails(dataset)
    print "Trail", t, "Accuracy:", acc
    score += acc

print score / num_trails
```

The dataset can be found at http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation

I'm being baffled with the output of the program:

```
Trail 0 Accuracy: 0.758503401361
Trail 1 Accuracy: 0.84693877551
Trail 2 Accuracy: 0.926870748299
Trail 3 Accuracy: 0.96768707483
Trail 4 Accuracy: 0.979591836735
Trail 5 Accuracy: 0.996598639456
Trail 6 Accuracy: 1.0
Trail 7 Accuracy: 1.0
Trail 8 Accuracy: 1.0
Trail 9 Accuracy: 1.0
0.947619047619
```

Here is the output if I remove the random.shuffle() in the method runTrail()

```
Class distributution: Counter({'unacc': 1210, 'acc': 384, 'good': 69, 'vgood': 65})
Trail 0 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 1 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 2 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 3 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 4 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 5 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 6 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 7 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 8 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
Trail 9 Accuracy: 0.583333333333
0.583333333333
```

I understand that shuffling can affect the accuracy of the algorithm matters in this dataset - since the dataset is ordered according to class.

Hence the accuracy is around 70 on the first iteration.

But why does the accuracy keep on increasing? It makes no sense to me. 
If the algorithm keeps being trained, it will perform better, but here I am using a new Instance **and** also shuffling the dataset.

Comment: It looks as if you original dataset would grow by duplicating the examples increasing the probability of having a test sample also appear in the training set making it possible for the models to overfit in the last iterations.

However by reading the code I could not spot the culprit. You should print the size of the `X_train`, `X_test`, `Y_train` and `Y_test` arrays in `runTrails` to check this hypothesis.

Comment: @ogrisel I printed the lengths : 
print len(X_train) , len(Y_train), len(X_test), len(Y_test)
1140 1140 588 588 
On all runs

Comment: Found the bug - I have to set the fit_prior argument to the constructor to false, or the prior probabilities will be considered.

Comment: That does not explain why the prior would change from one run to the next.

Comment: I am a noob when it comes to probability. Can you please explain first what prior is and why it would (or wouldn't) change from one run to the next?

Comment: The class prior is the probability P(y=k) of a sample belonging to class k, without (prior to) considering the sample's features. Naive Bayes makes decision based on P(y=k) × P(y=k|x) where the latter term does take the features into account. When `fit_prior=True`, the class prior distribution is estimated from the relative frequencies of the different classes.